# Input form inside canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, input

I'm wondering if there was any way to get an input from the user, preferably to a texbox (or anywhere a user can see what he's writting) in a canvas element through javascript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Position a textbox over the top of the canvas element using absolute positioning.

my suggested layout is something like:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:800px;height:800px">
    <canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:300px;width:600px; etc...." />
</div>
```

with this you have the relative positioned `<div>` to base where your going to pop things up over, I would probably also add a modal backdrop...

hope this helps -ck

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried yet but seems it will probably work. How would I go about to get the inputed text aterwards?

Comment: via JavaScript? you would access it through its `.value` property

Comment: Thanks, I'm relatively new to JS.

Comment: it's ok, everyone has to start somewhere, you might want to try jQuery (http://jquery.com) as it makes simple things like this easier

Comment: Oh, I am using JQuery. Might've forgot to mention that. I just use .fadeIn('fast') and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Question is a bit old, but I wanted to provide an alternative to absolute positioning.  You can set the background-image (presumably to a div bigger than your textbox).  Here's an example:

HTML:

```
...<canvas id="canvas"></canvas> <div id="backDrop">...[your textbox]</div>...
```

Javascript:

```
$('#backDrop').css('background-image', 'url(' + document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL() + ')');
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dn3Zb/1/) as an example.

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971249/html5-canvas-as-css-background-image), this essentially takes a snapshot of the canvas at the point you set the background-image property.  Any changes you make to the canvas after setting the background-image will not be reflected (unless you re-set it), but this is probably what you want in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

There is a canvas input library. It does not use any DOM elements, but is built purely on canvas. You can read more more about it and download it at http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/108/CanvasInput-HTML5-Canvas-Text-Input . It's open-source.

Comment: Actually, it does use a hidden DOM input element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try it with the following:

```
<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;position:absolute;width:[amount by programmer];height:[amount by programmer];border-style:solid;border-color:[if wanted];">
<canvas style="width:700px;height:700px;"></canvas>
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;width:[amount by programmer];height:[amount by programmer];"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a responsive canvas with an input (for a chat). With a position:fixed input (without padding, border, etc) that had the same background color as the canvas, i managed to position the input exactly on top of the canvas and let it scale, no matter the width/height of the browser window. WORKS LIKE A CHARM! This is the javascript i used (ofcourse you'll have to adjust the values to fit your area):

```
window.addEventListener("resize", deviceCheckResize);
    
function deviceCheckResize()
{
    ge("mp_input").style.left = (ge("myCanvas").offsetLeft + ge("myCanvas").offsetWidth*0.670) + "px";
    ge("mp_input").style.top = (ge("myCanvas").offsetTop + ge("myCanvas").offsetHeight * 0.914) + "px";
    
    tempHeight = (ge("myCanvas").offsetHeight * 0.055);
    ge("mp_input").style.height = tempHeight + "px";
    ge("mp_input").style.lineHeight = tempHeight + "px";
    ge("mp_input").style.width = (ge("myCanvas").offsetWidth * 0.243) + "px";
    ge("mp_input").style.fontSize = (w/64) + "px";

}
```