# HTML5 Canvas as CSS background-image?

Tags: css, html, canvas

Is it possible to make the background image of a DIV a canvas that can be modified with getContext("2d")?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can have a canvas inside the div with absolute css position, other elements have to have z-index greater than the canvas.

Answer (score 31):

Well, you could place a canvas element inside of the div, maximize its height and width, set its position to relative and its z-index to a negative value.

However, if you want to use a real CSS `background-image:...` you would have to create your image inside your canvas. You could then use [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) to get a data url which you could use as value for your original `background-image`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
var myElement = document.getElementById('myelement');

myElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+data+')';
```

If you don't want to create a *new* background but manipulate an existing one, load your original background into an Image object (or get a reference) and use [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29):

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(this,0,0);
    someCallbackToManipulateTheImage();
}
var src = myElement.style.backgroundImage.substr(4);
src.substr(0,src.length - 1);
image.src = src;
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a canvas as multiple background DIV's backgroud-image without insert multiple canvas or generate multiple data url's just like --webkit-canvas? It will save memory if it is possible.. If it can specify the canvas URL in css file, it will much simplify programming since it doesn't need to insert canvas for every DIV with same backgrounds.

Comment: @sean: That's a whole other question, and comments aren't the right place to ask them. That being said, as soon as you use `toDataUrl`, you can use the generated url anywhere you want and reuse the canvas (or throw it away). Depends on your use case. But then, again, not the right place for follow-up questions.

Answer (score 8):

Set the background-image of the div to this:

```
"url('" + canvas.toDataURL() + "')";
```

Edit: At that point, note that you are also free to do what you wish with the canvas, as the background-image will continue to contain only the image data that was in the canvas at the moment that you called canvas.toDataURL().  Feel free to discard or draw onto the canvas, as it will not affect your div's background at that point.

Comment: Assuming this works as expected, both this and the chosen answer are 100% correct. This one an assignment of the background-image property in CSS, the other based on z-indexing.

Comment: I think this is more in tune of what the OP was looking for, to replace the representation of the dynamically drawn canvas with a static image, here encoded in the URL.