# CSS/JS: How do I copy the edge pixels and repeat them

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy, pixel

I have a 960px banner (with multiple slides) and as per request of the client, it should fill the whole window width, but not by scaling. They mentioned "pixel copying" but I have not yet found anything on it.

I have to make the banners edge (last 1px) repeat itself to fit the width; last left pixel should repeat to the left side and last right pixel should repeat to the right side.

I have to do it in HTML/CSS/JS, but I have not yet found a solution, sure I could accomplish this by just opening Photoshop, but the client is able to change the banner through the backend AND as I mentioned before; it contains slides (changing each 5 seconds or so..)

I was thinking like:

```
<script>
   var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'image.jpg';
    var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    data = context.getImageData(x, y, 960, 1).data;
    // ... Now what?
</script>
```

I found that code on Stackoverflow, but my problem is not only that I don't know how to get the pixel and copy it, but also EVERY pixel from top to bottom of the banner needs to be repeated

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this approach, using data URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9971339/36537

Essentially you create a 1px wide canvas, set the values from the banner pixels, and convert this to a data URL. Pass this data URL to the CSS background image property.

To get the pixel values and copy them into the new canvas(es), follow the information on MDN: [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)