# Slice / divide HTML content for animated slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have seen several examples of how people can slice up an image into a bunch of tiles that can be animated separately, but I can't find an example of how to do that with anything other than an image, but want to be able to do it with HTML content to get a visual result like this: http://wowslider.com/ but without forcing it to be an image.

Here is the Jsfiddle of an example with an image: http://jsfiddle.net/zvdnzx0f/

I have to include a little code here to link to JsFiddle, this code is relevant as it uses the Canvas clip(), but again, how to do it with HTML content.

```
//from: http://jsfiddle.net/y4gRw/
var objImg = new Image();
objImg.onload = function(){ drawIt();}
objImg.src = "http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/woman-super-hero-vector-illustrationon-background-34647925.jpg";

function drawIt(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-id");
  if(canvas.getContext){
    var ctx= canvas .getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(objImg, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't be trivial. The fiddle you provided clones the image to a background image for the tiles. Therefore you will need something like: http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/ to create an image of the HTML then something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971249/html5-canvas-as-css-background-image to make it a background image. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, that is a decent idea. I see from this slider: http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-wordpress-3d-demo-slider/ where they chose to fade out all the HTML elements and then apply the effects only to the image. I may try your rasterize idea, but if not at least I have another option.

Comment: you can also make image slider and add your html content over it by float or position absolute or something don't you think....