# creating a png from a part of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a couple of input fields which will get populated by users. Additionally, I have a field that displays the current time and an image that gets chosen by the user. I packed everything in a `<div id="container">`  Now I want to save this div as a .png when the user hits a button.

What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking of drawing everything in canvas but I am not sure if that is possible or a good way. 
I tried this set up here [Input form inside canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405772/input-form-inside-canvas-element)

but the input is not even in the canvas, so when I download the canvas as a picture the input is not in it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks !

Comment: _"and an image that gets chosen by the user"_ Is image uploaded by user ?

Comment: --> [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Comment: If all content is on the same domain, consider [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Quick and Dirty Demo:**

How to annotate and timestamp a clicked image and then let the user save it locally:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var currentImg,currentText;

draw();

$('img').on('click',function(){
  currentImg=this;
  draw();
});

//
$('#text').on('keyup',function(e){
  currentText=($(this).val());
  draw();
});

//
$('#save').click(function(){
  $('<br>Right-Click the image below to save it<br>').appendTo('body');
  $('<img />',{
    src:canvas.toDataURL(),
  })
  .addClass('withBorder')
  .appendTo('body');
});


function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillText(new Date(),5,20);
  if(currentText){ ctx.fillText(currentText,5,35); }
  if(currentImg){ ctx.drawImage(currentImg,0,50); }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
.withBorder{border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on a car of your choice</h4>
<img crossOrigin='anonymous' src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car1.png'>
<img crossOrigin='anonymous' src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car2.png'>
<br>
Comment:&nbsp;<input type='text' id=text>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
<br>
<button id='save'>Save</button>
```

Comment: W-O-W. Thank you so much! Ok, so from my understanding, you have to redraw everything with javasctipt in canvas in order to display it.

Comment: @klausruprecht. Correct. Html5 canvas is the export mechanism. (Html2Canvas works the same way by attempting to draw all the html elements in a div onto the canvas and then using Canvas's export-to-image capability to create an image).

Comment: I have one more question, so the code works fine but when I use a picture of a non CROS origin domain (http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrfoQlZuWxvyT3lLxjZIz3G5A6EIRWRe3MYGyQbFC7rwJ4ScvBoRbEKXU), the picture gets displayed in the canvas but not not in the downloaded picture. Is that because the domain doesn't support CORS or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Drawing a cross-domain image onto the canvas will taint the canvas which will prevent `.toDataURL`. In your production version you will host the images on the same domain as your webpage. Alternatively you can use `input type='file'` or the `FileReader API` to let the users load images from their local disk storage.

Comment: ok, so there is no other way than storing the picture locally and then using it?

Comment: Well, you can never violate CORS. Typically images come from either your website or are supplied from the user's local drive. If you want to use cross-domain images you will have to ask the other domain to deliver images in a CORS compliant way. Those are the 3 most common ways of delivering images. A 4th way is to route cross-domain images through your web server which results in CORS compliance because the image & webpage are then again delivered by your web server. This is seriously NOT recommended because it exposes your web server to uncontrollable load and possible malware infestation.

Comment: Is it possible to write this code without global variables?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner, Your comment is off-topic to this Q&A, but yes, you could enclose the code (almost any code) inside an Immediately Executing Function Expression, (commonly called an IIFE) to keep the variables out of the global scope: `var myIIFE=(function () { ...code... })();`