# How to append(show) a div to a canvas arc after hovering on the canvas arc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Simply, my program is to put annotations on image. when the user clicks with the mouse on specific point on the image, it draws a canvas arc containing a number(that is working).
What i wanna add is when the user clicks on the image, it draws the canvas arc containing a number and shows a div containing two editable text areas and when the mouse leaves, the 2 text areas go hidden with respect to save the position of each annotation with the values in the 2 text areas.

here is my code:

```
<canvas width="1600" height="1600" 
style="background-image:url('dermatome.jpg');" id="special">
    <div id="re">
        <textarea id="text1" rows="4" cols="50" hidden></textarea>
        <textarea id="text2" rows="4" cols="50" hidden></textarea>
    </div>
</canvas>

    <script>

     var count = 1;

     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $("#special").click(function(e){ 

        //get mouse coordinates
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 


        var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); 
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(x, y, 20,0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font = '17pt Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
        ctx.fillText(count, x, y);
        count++;

        $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $('#re').show();    })         });         })         </script>
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551936/creating-a-png-from-a-part-of-html/31552694#31552694) is starting code for you. It lets you 1. Select from a set of images, 2. Type in some annotating text, 3. Save the annotated image as an img element on the page.

Comment: it doesn't solve solve the problem. i want every drawn node to have 2 editable text boxes an when hovering on a drawn one it shows me the content i wrote inside it

Answer (score 0):

> What i wanna add is when the user clicks on the image [**#1**], it
>   draws the canvas arc containing a number [**#2**] and shows a div
>   containing two editable text areas [**#3**] and when the mouse leaves
>   [**#4**], the 2 text areas go hidden [**#5**] with respect to save the
>   position of each annotation with the values in the 2 text areas
>   [**#6**].

1. Listen for clicks on the canvas using #special's `.click`.
2. Use your "numbered arc" code from your question.
3. Canvas cannot be a parent so wrap #special & #re in a new container div (#wrapper).

   - Set #wrapper as `position:relative` and #special & #re as `position:absolute`.
   - On #special's click, set #re's `left` & `top` positions to the click position.
   - Use #re's `.show` to toggle its visibility to visible.
   - Use #text1's & #text2's `.val` to fill / clear their text contents as desired. If you want to re-show the users previous texts, fetch those previous texts from the appropriate javascript object and refill the text using `.val(annotations[n].text1) and .val(annotations[n].text2)`.
4. "...when the mouse leaves" ... hmmmmmm, leaves what? Perhaps help the user understand better by adding a "Save" button with the 2 textareas.
5. Use #re's `.hide` to toggle its visibility to hidden.
6. Use a javascript object to save the click position and the textarea values.

   ```
   var annotations=[];
   annotations.push({
       x:x, // == x from #special's click handler
       y:y, // == y from #special's click handler
       text1: $('#text1').val(),
       text2: $('#text2').val(),    
   });
   ```

If you want the user be able to click on a previous numbered circle, you can test the mouseclick position vs each [x,y] in annotations[] using this mouse-in-circle formula:

```
var dx=mouseX-annotations[n].x;
var dy=mouseY-annotations[n].y;
if(dx*dx+dy*dy<20*20){  // 20 is the radius of your circle ;-)
    // the mouse is inside circle#n
}
```

Comment: the image is blocked from clicking and i don't know why so please if you can translate your points into code that suits my code sitiuation (canvas, count, etc).

Comment: how to select the drawn circle in order to show the text boxes when hover on it and then hides when the mouse leaves it????????????

Comment: Regardng `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`: The last bit of code (`dx*dx+dy*dy<20*20`) gives you the ability to check if the mouse is above or outside of any of your circles.

Comment: regarding the last piece if code needs more explanation please         var dx=mouseX-annotations[n].x;
var dy=mouseY-annotations[n].y;
if(dx*dx+dy*dy<20*20){  // 20 is the radius of your circle ;-)
    // the mouse is inside circle#n
}

Comment: Test all circles on `mousemove`. For any circle `dx*dx+dy*dy<20*20` will be true if that circle has focus and will be false if that circle doesn't have focus (==is blurred). If true, that circle has focus so show your textareas for that circle. A performance trick: When a circle gets focus, save it's reference number so that you won't have to repeatedly re-show the textareas until the circle loses focus. Good luck with your project!

Comment: How can i define (n) in var dx=mouseX-annotations[n].x;??

Comment: Also (x,y)  in var dx=mouseX-annotations[n].x

Comment: You can use any name that you want, but I illustrate with an `annotations[]` array that contains a javascript object for each number-circle {x:, y:, text1:, text2:} that the user has defined.