# How to have an input field appear on top of a canvas in html

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am trying to have an input field appear on top of a canvas, and position the input field precisely. [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405772/input-form-inside-canvas-element) was asked 7 years ago, but the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

One try was this:

```
 <html>
 <body>

     <div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;position:absolute;width:700;height:700;border-style:solid">
     <canvas style="width:700px;height:700px;"></canvas>
     <input type="text" style="position:absolute;width:30;height:30;z-index:2"/></div>
```

and another try was this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
     <div style="position:relative;width:800px;height:800px">
         <canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
         <input type="text" "position:absolute;left:100px;top:300px;width:600px " />
     </div>
 <body>
```

Using the chrome browser on the Macintosh, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt is correct, your just missing the style property in front of your style string on your input element.

```
<html>
 <body>
     <div style="position:relative;width:800px;height:800px">
         <canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
         <input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:300px;width:600px " />
     </div>
 <body>
```